# Vya taillight won't go out

Tags: led-lights, taillight

I have a Light and Motion Vya Taillight which won't turn off when removed from mounting socket. I've wiped down the contacts. Is there anything else to try?

Comment: Do you mean it does not turn off when removed from it's mounting socket?

Comment: yes, I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @fgregg have you tried contacting Light and Motion regarding this issue?